# Displaying PDF & images from azure blob container

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure-blob-storage

I got the exact URL of the files. when I click the button its directly download the file.
I need to display the file in the below tag

```
  <embed ng-src="{{FileURL}}" type="application/pdf" style="width:550px;height:350px;">
```

Comment: This is an open issue in angular https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/339 related to `embed ng-src`. Check the workaround posted there.

Comment: This is not the problem of embed & ng-src. when I copy and paste the URL in the tab it's downloading the file. but not displaying the file

Comment: No, it's problem of angular or embed itself since dynamically updating src does not reflect. You can check by just plain html like `<embed src="<pdf URL>" type="application/pdf" >` which works fine.

Comment: @krishg If it works for you, can you send a screenshot of your running results as an answer,  thank you.

Comment: @jason-pan , what works for me? Plain html without Angular is what works. But that's not what OP asks. It's just to confirm that issue is with dynamically updating src of embed via ng-src.

Comment: @krishg Okay, I thought `<embed src="<pdf URL>" type="application/pdf" >` is a valid answer?

Comment: @jason-pan , no problem. Also if you have any alternate solution, please go ahead to post as answer. Another solution I had was to use [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer)